# Connect with MongoHub to MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, mlab

Why I can not connect with MongoHub to MongoLab?

Here is the connection string:

[image]

Here is the MongoHub settings I filled in (*mongodb://ds053708.mongolab.com*)
password / username is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MongoDB's standard connection string URI format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) is:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

So in your case, your host is `ds053708.mongolab.com`.

If you're still having problems you can check out MongoLab's doc on [troubleshooting connection issues](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#help). One of the first things I usually double-check is whether you're using your MongoLab account credentials or your database credentials. They are two different things and in this case you want to use the latter.

Of course, we're always happy to help at support@mongolab.com.